# Cordova plugin with asset

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

I want to write a **simple cordova plugin** that *contains* my **asset file** (image, some JSON file) (for android, ios,...)

I want to see a simple plugin source as a hello world to learn how to use plugin assets in the main application
For example how to refer to an image source file that belongs to a plugin and how cordova plugins work.

Thanks for your attention and sorry for my poor English skills.

Comment: Any news on this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Inside `plugin.xml` file, use something like:

```
<resource-file src="FooPluginStrings.xml" target="res/values/FooPluginStrings.xml" />
OR
<resource-file src="src/android/assets/small.pdf" target="assets/small.pdf" />
```

For details read the plugin spec posted by @daserge.

Answer (score -1):

See [cordova-plugin-inappbrowser](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/blob/c630159c2201f566c881add1ed7f8445ef664011/plugin.xml#L216) and [`asset`](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/7.x/plugin_ref/spec.html#asset) tag specifically as an example.

[Cordova plugin development guide](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_hybrid_plugins_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide)

[Cordova plugin specification](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/plugin_ref_spec.md.html#Plugin%20Specification)